# What are the conditions under which an adapter doesn't update attached view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I am using this library to create swipe-able cards : https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

The view which makes the swipe-able cards control, gets attached to an adapter and sources it's drawing from it.

In my implementation, every card has a button, and when it is clicked, something in the source array changes, for which I want to refresh the whole card list. I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the associated adapter, but the `getView()` never gets called in the adapter to see any updates.

What's strange is that the same adapter works perfectly with a ListView

Is there any specific requirement either in the adapter's side or in the view itself which is required for the proper functioning of notifyDataSetChanged?

**My Code:**
(Please ignore the absence of ViewHolder pattern and the presence of click receivers inside the adapter. Code quality is the least thing I can be concerned about right now when a crucial functionality isn't working)

**Adapter (using Array Adapter)**

```
public class TourCardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TourCardBean> implements View.OnClickListener {

    Context context;
    ToursFragment.ToursControlsClickListener clickListener;

    public TourCardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TourCardBean> tourCardsArr, ToursFragment.ToursControlsClickListener clickListener) {
        super(context, 0, tourCardsArr);
        this.context = context;
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        TourCardBean tourCard = getItem(position);

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_tour, parent, false);


        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.title = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.detail = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.detail);
        viewHolder.likeCount = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.likeCount);
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.cardLocationImage);
        viewHolder.likeButton = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.cardLikeImage);
        viewHolder.shareButton = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.cardShareImage);

        viewHolder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.shareButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        viewHolder.title.setText(tourCard.getTitle());
        viewHolder.detail.setText(tourCard.getDetails());
        viewHolder.likeCount.setText("" + tourCard.getLikeCount());
        viewHolder.likeButton.setTag(tourCard.getId());
        viewHolder.shareButton.setTag(tourCard.getId());

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.cardLikeImage:
                clickListener.onLikeClick((int) v.getTag());
                break;
            case R.id.cardShareImage:
                clickListener.onShareClick((int) v.getTag());
                break;
        }
    }


    /**
     * View Holder for ListView
     *
     * @author Aman Alam
     */
    class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;
        public ImageView likeButton;
        public ImageView shareButton;
        public TextView title;
        public TextView detail;
        public TextView likeCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on some of the issues logged against the Swipecards library, it appears that it may have bugs that prevent it from updating the views on `notifyDataSetChanged()`. [This one](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards/issues/29) has a couple of workarounds that might work for you. Specifically, `flingContainer.removeAllViewsInLayout()`.

Comment: @Bradford2000 This was very helpful, the whole issue link. Thank you so much! :)
Can you please write it as an answer so that I can accept it as a correct answer?

Comment: Done. Glad that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some of the issues logged against the Swipecards library, it appears that it may have bugs that prevent it from updating the views on `notifyDataSetChanged()`. [This one](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards/issues/29) has a couple of workarounds that might work for you. Specifically, `flingContainer.removeAllViewsInLayout()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it took me 3-4 days of struggle to come to this place and find your solution :)

Answer (score 2):

If it works with the `ListView`, your Adapter shouldn't be the problem.

The [`SwipeFlingAdapterView`](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/lorentzos/flingswipe/SwipeFlingAdapterView.java) is (more or less) directly based on `AdapterView` which doesn't call `getView()` at all. So it's its responsibility to make a call to `getView()` when the dataset was changed. The relevant portion of the code seems to be, which might be blocked by your click event:

```
if (this.flingCardListener.isTouching()) {
    PointF lastPoint = this.flingCardListener.getLastPoint();
    if (this.mLastTouchPoint == null || !this.mLastTouchPoint.equals(lastPoint)) {
        this.mLastTouchPoint = lastPoint;
        removeViewsInLayout(0, LAST_OBJECT_IN_STACK);
        layoutChildren(1, adapterCount);
    }
}
```

Overall the `SwipeFlingAdapterView` doesn't seem to be prepared for a dataset change event at all.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries can be very useful, but I think it is wise you use the support library offered by google.
You get the benefits of getting the latest updates in material design as soon they are released.
You can declare in your gradle file. this;

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Comment: I am afraid, this is not the answer to this question. Android's design support library doesn't let me create swipeable cards like tinder, and neither is the library that I am using is a part of design support library, so this answer is irrelevant.